# Scrollify.js - enable scrollbar based on condition

Tags: jquery, jquery-scrollify

Is it possible to enable scrollbar (i.e. set to true) based on section index value? I tried below code, but it doesn't give the output.

```
before:function(index, section) {   
    if(index>3){    
        $.scrollify({
            scrollbars:true
        });                                 
    }
    else{
        $.scrollify({
            scrollbars:false
        });
    }
}
```

What is wrong with this code?

I wanted to enable scroll bar once crossed 4th section.

Comment: Is index started with 0 or 1?

Comment: index started with 0

Comment: @Kashyap here issue is not about the index value, it may be 3 or 4. I wanted to enable or disable scrollbars based on the condition.!

Answer (score 0):

I don't find any solution to do with this scrollify.js by default. So came up with my own code to solve this issue.

I set `overflow` of `body` tag `hidden` by on page load, and done with things on `before()`.

```
before:function(index, sections) {                  
    if(index>2){
        $('body').removeAttr('style');
    }
    else{
        $('body').css('overflow','hidden');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Scrollify provides a method to do this. `$.scrollify.setOptions()`.

Your first example won't work because you're re-initialising Scrollify.

Comment: I tried this on before, but not working!!

var optionsTrue={scrollbars:true};
var optionsFalse={scrollbars:false};
if(index>2){
 $.scrollify.setOptions(optionsTrue);
}
else{
 $.scrollify.setOptions(optionsFalse);
}